# how to customize a PXSelector with PXCustomizeBaseAttribute

Tags: acumatica

I'm not sure how to use the PXCustomizeBaseAttribute with a _CacheAttached() event handler in order to change the selector that is being used on a field.  I have this which is complaining about the second parameter:

```
 [PXCustomizeBaseAttribute(typeof(PXSelectorAttribute), null, typeof(Search<CRCampaign.campaignID,
        Where<CRCampaign.isActive, Equal<True>>>))]
```

The second parameter is supposed to be a property name but, not sure what to set it to for a selector.

Is there a better way to do this?

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PXCustomizeBaseAttribute is typically used to redefine just a single property of a DAC's attribute for a particular screen such as its UI display name.

to replace the current attribute with another you would do the following :

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
[PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(PXSelectorAttribute))]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<CRCampaign.campaignID,
        Where<CRCampaign.isActive, Equal<True>>>), SubstituteKey= typeof(CRCampaign.campaignCD)
protected void DAC_FIELD_CacheAttached(PXCache sender) { }
```